# Did the Early Church Fathers condemn polygamy?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, early-church, morality, polygamy

Today I was debating with a Christian who believes in polygamy and claimed that the Early Church Fathers allowed for the act of polygamy, is that true and is there any evidence that the Early Church condemned the act of polygamy (ie marriage to more than one spouse at a time).

Answer (score 1):

## Paul only prohibits it for church leaders.

In his letter to Timothy, Paul writes:

> Therefore an overseer must be above reproach, the husband of one wife, sober-minded, self-controlled, respectable, hospitable, able to teach, not a drunkard, not violent but gentle, not quarrelsome, not a lover of money. He must manage his own household well, with all dignity keeping his children submissive, for if someone does not know how to manage his own household, how will he care for God’s church?

1 Timothy 3:2-5

Given that this letter was written in the context of a polygamous culture, it can therefore be reasoned that Paul wasn't prohibiting polygamy entirely, but only banning polygamists from attaining positions of power in the church, along with banning those in power in the church from abusing that power to accumulate multiple wives.

I don't know what other early church fathers said in writings outside the Bible, but it's my understanding that strict monogamy was a primarily Greek and Roman thing at the time of the early Church, it entered the Church through Greek and Roman converts, and that the Catholic Church eventually enforced it on Medieval kings in order to gain political power over them by controlling their wedding alliances. I don't have any citations for that, though.

Comment: **Does St. Paul really mean to say that polygamy not acceptable only for church leaders?** Many critics of polygamy also point to the Pauline epistles that state that church officials should be respectable, above reproach, and the husband of a single wife (1 Timothy 3,Titus 1). The Greek phrase ***mias gunaikos andra*** is an unusual Greek construction, capable of being translated in multiple ways, including (but not limited to): 1) "one wife man," (prohibiting plural marriage) or 2) "a wife man" (requiring elders to be married) or 3) "first wife man" (prohibiting divorcés from ordination).

Comment: @KenGraham Paul was writing in the context of a polygamous culture, to another member of that culture, and Jesus had prohibited Christians from divorcing. It was probably either option one or two.

Comment: St. Paul wrote to Timothy in Greek. The Greek culture was monogamous and not polygamist. Timothy was a native of Lystra or of Derbe in Lycaonia (Anatolia) and not Palestine. St. Paul wrote his ***Epistle to the Hebrews*** in Aramaic. It was addressed to their culture.

Comment: @KenGraham Both Paul and Timothy were Hebrews - though the latter had one Gentile parent.

Comment: Timothy was Of the Greek culture. He only became circumcised because of the circumcision dispute. **Paul came also to Derbe and Lystra. A disciple was there, named Timothy, the son of a Jewish woman who was a believer; but his father was a Greek. He was well spoken of by the brethren at Lystra and Iconium. Paul wanted Timothy to accompany him; and he took him and circumcised him because of the Jews that were in those places, for they all knew that his father was a Greek.**

Answer (score 1):

**Did the Early Church Fathers condemn polygamy?**

The short answer is **yes**.

[Tertullian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertullian) (155-220), wrote that marriage is lawful, but polygamy is not:

> We do not indeed forbid the union of man and woman, blest by God as the seminary of the human race, and devised for the replenishment of the earth and the furnishing of the world, and therefore permitted, yet singly.  For Adam was the one husband of Eve, and Eve his one wife, one woman, one rib.  We grant, that among our ancestors, and the patriarchs themselves, it was lawful not only to marry, but even to multiply wives.  There were concubines, too, (in those days.)  But although the Church did come in figuratively in the synagogue, yet (to interpret simply) it was necessary to institute (certain things) which should afterward deserve to be either lopped off or modified.  For the Law was (in due time) to supervene.  (Nor was that enough:)  for it was meet that causes for making up the deficiencies of the Law should have forerun (Him who was to supply those deficiencies).  And so to the Law presently had to succeed the Word of God introducing the spiritual circumcision.  Therefore, by means of the wide licence of those days, materials for subsequent emendations were furnished beforehand, of which materials the Lord by His Gospel, and then the apostle in the last days of the (Jewish) age, either cut off the redundancies or regulated the disorders. - [Marriage Lawful, But Not Polygamy.](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Ante-Nicene_Fathers/Volume_IV/Tertullian:_Part_Fourth/To_His_Wife/I/Chapter_2)

Justin Martyr, Irenaeus and Tertullian all spoke against polygamy, condemning it. Tertullian explicitly tackled the objection that polygamy was allowed for the patriarchs.

The monogamy of the Roman Empire was the cause of two explanatory notes in the writings of Josephus describing how the polygamous marriages of Herod the Great were permitted under Jewish custom.

Some of *The Dead Sea Scrolls* show that several smaller Jewish sects [forbade polygamy](https://books.google.ca/books?id=fUPIG-TEKR8C&pg=PA380&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) before and during the time of Jesus.

Although some have argued that St. Paul may have seemingly allowed polygamy in some cases except for bishops or church leaders. This is in direct conflict with Church Fathers and not a Catholic interpretation of the Sacred Texts. They make mention of [1 Timothy 3: 1-5](https://www.newadvent.org/bible/1ti003.htm). Many critics of polygamy also point to the Pauline epistles that state that church officials should be respectable, above reproach, and the husband of a single wife (1 Timothy 3,[Titus 1](https://www.newadvent.org/bible/tit001.htm)).

The Greek phrase ***mias gunaikos andra*** is an unusual Greek construction, capable of being translated in multiple ways, including (but not limited to): 1) "one wife man," (prohibiting plural marriage) or 2) "a wife man" (requiring elders to be married) or 3) "first wife man" (prohibiting divorcés from ordination).

**1 Timothy 3: 1-5:**

> 1 It is well said, When a man aspires to a bishopric, it is no mean employment that he covets. 2 The man who is to be a bishop, then, must be one with whom no fault can be found; faithful to one wife, sober, discreet, modest, well behaved, hospitable, experienced in teaching, 3 no lover of wine or of brawling, courteous, neither quarrelsome nor grasping. 4 He must be one who is a good head to his own family, and keeps his children in order by winning their full respect; 5 if a man has not learned how to manage his own household, will he know how to govern God’s church?

> 1 Fidelis sermo: si quis episcopatum desiderat, bonum opus desiderat. 2 Oportet ergo episcopum irreprehensibilem esse, unius uxoris virum, sobrium, prudentem, ornatum, pudicum, hospitalem, doctorem, 3 non vinolentum, non percussorem, sed modestum: non litigiosum, non cupidum, sed 4 suæ domui bene præpositum: filios habentem subditos cum omni castitate. 5 Si quis autem domui suæ præesse nescit, quomodo ecclesiæ Dei diligentiam habebit?

> 1 Πιστὸς ὁ λόγος: εἴ τις ἐπισκοπῆς ὀρέγεται, καλοῦ ἔργου ἐπιθυμεῖ. 2 δεῖ οὖν τὸν ἐπίσκοπον ἀνεπίλημπτον εἶναι, μιᾶς γυναικὸς ἄνδρα, νηφάλιον, σώφρονα, κόσμιον, φιλόξενον, διδακτικόν, 3 μὴ πάροινον, μὴ πλήκτην, ἀλλὰ ἐπιεικῆ, ἄμαχον, ἀφιλάργυρον, 4 τοῦ ἰδίου οἴκου καλῶς προϊστάμενον, τέκνα ἔχοντα ἐν ὑποταγῇ μετὰ πάσης σεμνότητος: 5 εἰ δέ τις τοῦ ἰδίου οἴκου προστῆναι οὐκ οἶδεν, πῶς ἐκκλησίας θεοῦ ἐπιμελήσεται.

Answer (score 0):

"Appendix A: Authorities Referenced at [[the Council of] Trent](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5861)" of Brugger's [*The Indissolubility of Marriage and the Council of Trent*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6570), pp. 149-99, cites many who directly or indirectly condemn polygamy by reaffirming the [indissolubility of marriage](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34169&randomterm=false).

A succinct one is ([*ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6570), p. 153):

> Ambrose (339–97)
>
> *De patriarcha Abraham*, lib. 1, cap. 7, no. 79 ([PL 14](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6911):[442](https://archive.org/details/patrologiaecur14mign/page/n220/mode/2up), referenced at [CT, IX](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7806), 411n4):
>
> It is not licit for you if your wife still lives to take another wife. For indeed to seek another when you have your own is the crime of adultery; this is most serious, because you think in your sin that you should seek freedom in the law [to divorce].
>
> Non licet tibi, uxore vivente uxorem ducere. Nam et aliam quaerere, cum habeas tuam, crimen est adulterii, hoc gravius, quod putas peccato tuo auctoritatem lege quaerendam.

Comment: Neither of those are addressing polygamy, but divorce and remarriage. A polygamist doesn't divorce his first wife when he takes his second, after all.

Comment: @nick012000 St. Ambrose doesn't mention dismissing/divorcing. (The quote comes from  his treatise on the patriarch St. Abraham, who was polygamous; God permitted polygamy in his time.)

Comment: Is the Council of Trent considered "Early Church Fathers"?

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that Ambrose was born into a Roman Christian family.

Comment: @MikeBorden No, but Council of Trent fathers cited early Church Fathers.

Answer (score 0):

the Greek word    “  μιαν    mia   “      -      means  A    certain object- or  A   certain person - or mia can mean  first,  or mia  can mean - to agree in   unity.

the Greek word  εἷς -  heis     always means- a primary numeral  one    only  one.

μιαν  -   mia - mee'-ah   -  meaning   =   first: - or  -    a  (certain)- or agree / unity

εἷς -  heis - hice -  meaning  =   A  primary  numeral  one:        only   -   one  and no more,  singular

Mia is not the Greek word  mean  a primary  numeral  one.

as  we  see  here  in   -    tit 1:6  bishops -  the husband of  A   “   μία  Mia  “  wife.

the bishop is to be the husband of  A  wife      -    -   this  Greek word   is  Mia.    if the  bishop  is only  supposed to be limited  to being  married  of  only  one  singular  wife -  the  Greek word in the bible would be    “    εἷς       -  heis   “         -  a primary  numeral  one  -   no  more than  one.  singular.

1st ti 3: 2 , 12      deacons, bishops be husband of one  A    “    μία    Mia  “ wife.

**never in the bible is the word  one  used  to  command any man  to only  be married  to only  one  singular  wife.**     -   -   every single last scripture suggesting that bishops, deacons and churchmen to be the husband of  A  wife, never uses the word     “    εἷς       -  heis   “     meaning 1 wife,  as in *( a primary number 1. )

heis 1.  wife  - NEVER EXISTS IN THE MANUSCRIPTS

but it is simply promoting the idea that  the elders and church leaders  are to be married.  the authors of scriptures could have easily come out against polygamy in many ways.  but it is the total opposite.  the bible is pro polygamy.

Another  anti  polygamy translation  -   is found in  1co 7:2

1co 7:2  nevertheless, to avoid     fornication, let every man have his “   own    “  wife, and let every woman have
her  “   own    “ husband,

but this is not what the manuscripts say  -    notice the two words  in the verse  -

“    own  “    wife      -   and    -    own  husband

these are two completely different Greek words with two totally different meanings and definitions, only one of these words are actually the word   meaning     “  **own**  “

so, when you read the Trinitarian translation that says in
1co 7:2   that  every man have his  “   own  “   wife, and every woman have   her “   own    “  husband

this has nothing whatsoever to do with what the actual manuscripts are saying .

here is the exact manuscript translation - word for word of - 1co 7:2

1co 7:1  now concerning the things whereof ye wrote unto me: it is good for a man not to touch a woman.

:2  δια by     -     δε   also      -      τας   this      -      πορνειας   is fornication,
-

εκαστος    each man      -      την   they      -      εαυτου   themselves      -      γυναικα   woman      -
εχετω   have      -      και   and      -       εκαστη   each woman      -τον   their      -      ιδιον   own    -    ανδρα   man      -     εχετω   have

meaning   =  =     :2      BY  ALSO  THIS  IS  FORNICATION,   EACH  MAN  THEY  THEMSELVES  A  WOMAN  HAVE,  EACH WOMAN  THEIR  OWN  MAN  HAVE.

__these two words  in the translation that are repeated twice  as  “ own  “   -  these are not the same Greek words.  The word   -   heautou -  ἑαυτοῦ  -  referring to the men  is the Greek word  - heautou  -

the word is not “  idios  -   own  “   - it simply means     “      heautou    themselves   “

heautou -    ἑαυτοῦ
themselves -  heautou - heh-ow-too' )  is a pronoun  meaning    -   your self   -  selves ) our  selves  (thine) self (-selves ),
heautou   =  (a  reflexive pronoun of the 3rd person) –  ("himself, herself, itself," etc.) the word    heautou - heh-ow-too'    is the 3rd person reflexive (singular, plural) form which also functions as the reflexive for 1st and 2nd person.

it never says - let every man have his   “  own  “   wife, this word has nothing to do with the word    “  own  “  in the way that the Trinitarians have translated it  -  they have altered and changed the verse.

But  IN FACT,,    -      IT DOES SAY    LET EVERY WOMAN  HAVE HER     “    idios     -    OWN   “   HUSBAND
the Greek word meaning  “   own  “  is the word   idios       “    ἴδιοσ   “      meaning   -  your   own  .
and let every woman have her own / private -    idios    man

own ; - idios - id'-ee-os (   meaning    =    private or separate:   apart, aside,  separate),   private (-ly),  separate, their (own).
this is a huge diference in the Trinitarian translation   -   than what we see in the manuscripts  .

so when the Jew uses the word -   פִּלֶגֶשׁ  -  pîyleyesh  /   pile yesh,  -  the combination of the two separate words of combining  “  pîyle  “  and  -  “ yhesh  “   meaning -    -
IN Hebrew  a   pîylegesh.  =   means   =   A   WONDERFUL   CONNECTING   WIFE ,      when the Hebrews pronounced the word  -  “   pîyle yesh   “  they did not see the word     -    “   concubine   “

the Trinitarian looks at the word  -  concubine   “   concu - bine   “  and  refused to translate this word  pîyleyesh  /   pile yesh,     into english, -  the Trinitarian translators refused to translate this word .....    -     the Trinitarians simply left the word in  -  Italian / Latin  -   and copied the Latin word straight over into the english translation.
“
to the Hebrews serving their god, they see this word in the way that their Hebrew language is structured.     the word  “  פִּלֶגֶשׁ   -  pîyleyesh  /   pile yesh   “

the combination of two words  “   pîyle   and   yesh.
פָּלָא     -  pil'îy    -  meaning   =    remarkable, amazing  - superb and wonderful.  The Hebrew word  -   פָּגַשׁ  -  pâwyesh   /  paw-yesh'  -  meaning   =   to come in contact with, -  to  meet with,    together)  to be joined  /  connected  together  -   uniting  together  -  to  come together.

this word   -  פָּלִיא     -  pil'îy    -  meaning   =    remarkable, amazing  - superb and wonderful is used in many, many verses just exactly like we see here in   -
2ch 2:9  even to prepare me timber in abundance: for the house which i am about to build shall be   “  wonderful    -  פָּלִיא     -  pil'îy    -       “  and great.

this is what the Hebrews imagined and thought when they used the word  “  -   pîyleyesh  /   pile yesh   “

as =   A   WONDERFUL   CONNECTING   WIFE , they thought of it as meaning   =  a  remarkable, great and  wonderful unification, joining or bridging together a wonderful connection to their family. the word concubine  is an Italian  word  for an  abused  prostitute  -  living in  sexual  slavery  and has nothing to do with the actual  meaning of the literal Hebrew  word in the manuscripts  -   that  describes  adding a new wife  into a family  of  god.

pîyleyesh     -  פִּילֶגֶשׁ  - “   paw –  le  _  yesh “

- pîyleyesh  /   pile yesh   “  as =        A   WONDERFUL   CONNECTING   WIFE      -  not  concubine

=  a  remarkable, great and  wonderful unification, joining or bridging together a wonderful connection to their family

a  wonderful  connecting  wife    -  not  concubine

this word  pîyleyesh     ==      pal – e     and  the  word   yesh  -  are  two separate words that are put together to make the  word

“   paw –  le         _  yesh  “

אִשָּׁה   -    ish-shaw'   -  meaning   =   a woman   -  a   female  or  a   wife, woman   or a  wife

פִּלְאִי     -   pil'îy    pâlîy'       -    pil-ee',    paw-lee'    =  meaning    remarkable: - marvelous and wonderful.

and the Hebrew word    “        -   פָּגַשׁ   -  pâwyesh   /  paw-yesh'    -       means  =    to come in contact with, -  to  meet with,    together)  to be joined  /  connected  together  -   uniting  together  -  to  come together.
“  means    to  attach or unite together in a grouping or unification. .   to  band  or join together   -   but in this context it means to  band  or  join  or  bridge  or connect or  add  or  unite  another wife into your family.

For some coincidental  and  unintentional    reason the  Greek word for wife, is also     " Gunay / Gunē    - or    Gumay

and we even have –    Greek and Hebrew historical linguistically reference  for    Pawlee   Guma -     Poly gamy. – a great wife.

Why do we need to change the manuscripts to promote an anti - polygamy narrative throughout the entire translation,  these examples are  not  even  all of the many changes that have been made through the entire translation  - could  demonstrate many, many more.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.